# VueJS router configuration not enabled

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs-routing

In my VueJS project, I have configured the routing in a file "router.js".

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import personDetails from './components/component.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    mode : 'history',
    base : '/',
    routes : [
        {
            path : '/:group/:id',
            name : 'personDetails',
            component : personDetails ,
            props : true
        }
    ]
})
```

In the main.js file, I enable the routing configuration like this:

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
new Vue({
  router,
  el : '#app',
 components : { App }
 }).$mount('#app')
```

This is my App.js file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view v-bind="$props" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  props : ['group', 'id'],
  mounted() {
    console.log('Mounted App')    
  }
}    
</script>
```

I run the project by running "vue-cli-service build" and "npx http-server ./dist" commands.

I notice that when I call the configured router like this - "http://localhost:8080/1234/56", I get a 404 error. However when I call the default URL "http://localhost:8080" I get a blank page, since the App is loaded without any routing parameters. I can see the console.log() statements added to main.js and App.js, but not the "personDetails" component.

I added a default router configuration, and that seems to be working.

```
{
   path : '/',
   redirect:'/456/123'
}
```

This default routing loads the 'personDetails' component with the path parameters mapped to 456 and 123.

Please give some tips to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `mode: 'history'`. More details here - [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

> Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper
> server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access
> http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser.
>
> To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all
> fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static
> assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives
> in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fallback proxy of `http-server` as a [catch-all redirect](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#catch-all-redirect): `npx http-server ./dist -P http://localhost:8080?`

Comment: Thanks @RWAM. This was a server-side configuration issue. The http-server did not know to map the route "http://localhost:8080/1234/56" to the Vue project (index.html). Adding the fallback proxy to the server routed it to the Ve app, after which vue-router loaded the component.